# Local extremum points and inflection points

Tags: real-analysis

Find all values of $a, b$ for which the function $f(x)=a x^{3}+b x^{4}+$ $x^{6}$ has a local minimum at zero.

Can I conclude that $ f$ cannot have local minimum at $x=0$ since $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=ax^3+bx^4+x^6$, then $f'(0)=0$ and  $f^{iii}(x)=6a$ (the first non-zero derivative of ODD order) so at $x=0$ is there is neither max nor min.

The Rule:

If $f'(a)=0$ and  the first non-zero derivative is of EVEN order at $x=a$ and is negative(positive), there is max (min) at $x=a$

If $f'(b)=0$ and the first non-zero derivative is of ODD order, there is neither min nor max at $x=b$.

If all the derivatives vanish at $x=c$, this method fails. Then check if the first derivative changes sign from positive (negative) to negative (positive) while passing through $x=c$, there is max (min) at $x=c$.
If the sign doesn't change there is neither max nor min at $x=c$

Comment: Sixth derivative is zero

Comment: Please check that $D^{(n)}(x^n)=n!$

Comment: Oh..you have written wrong ..the function in the question is a polynomial of degree 6

Comment: Oh! sorry it was a typom, thanks.

Comment: The first non zero derivative at $x=0$ is of third order , right? Since it is $6a$ when $a\neq 0$

Comment: @RIYASUDHEEN T. K , you are right, there is neither max nor min at $x=0$ in this example.

Comment: @ZAhmed It is worth mentioning that the rule fails if all derivatives are zero...

Comment: Yes, I have completed the issue by editing further.